# Error in Process.Start() – The System cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am Using the below code to fetch a file from database and print it with the selected printer from Installed Printers populated in the Dropdownlist, my problem is during using the **Printjob.Start()** it throws the Exception **The System cannot find the file specified**

My code is,

```
protected void ggvqpdetail_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.ToUpper().ToString() == "PRINTREC")
    {
        try
        {
            // Set the printer to a printer in the dropdown box when the selection changes. 
            PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
            string a = TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text + TextBox3.Text;
            DataSet ds = ExamManagement.SP.Eval_QP_PrintSelect(a).GetDataSet();
            if (ddlprint.SelectedIndex != -1 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                // The dropdown box's Text property returns the selected item's text, which is the printer name.
                printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = ddlprint.Text;

                Process printJob = new Process();
                printJob.StartInfo.FileName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Data"].ToString();
                printJob.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                printJob.StartInfo.Verb = "printto";
                printJob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                printJob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                printJob.StartInfo.Arguments = ddlprint.Text;
                printJob.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Data"].ToString());
                printJob.Start();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Lblmsg.Visible = true;
            Lblmsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what value does `printJob.StartInfo.FileName` hold after you debug over that line. It would need to be a name to a file that exists on the file system where the application is running.

Comment: Does your file path have spaces in it? If yes you have to put the path in quotation marks escaped with \".

Comment: A call to File.Exists(printJob.StartInfo.FileName) would prove the file exists on the system.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the problem would depends on that you actually place in that `printJob.StartInfo.FileName`. The value comes from the database, so the only person capable of investigating it is **you**. Look what filename you have in `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Data"]` and make sure is a file that exists and you have access to in on your local *client* where you're trying to print from. That, of course, also reveals the weakness of your solution which seems to store filenames in the database and expect the name to be a valid local file on each client. Very unlikely to be true.

Comment: The File does exists in the Database I am storing the file and Trying to fetch and Print that file in the Same Machine only

Comment: A database does not contain Files, so obviously the 'File' does **not** exists in the database. Get your terminology straight so we can actually communicate. Does your database contains a file *name* or a file *content*?

Comment: My Database table contains File Name and the Data of that File

Comment: And is `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Data"]` the file *name* or the file *data*?

Comment: It is the File data I had also tried with `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][Filename]` but the same exception was thrown

Comment: If the field expects the file name, replacing it with random content from data would not help, would it? Is the file name stored in `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][Filename]` a **valid, existing file name**? This is relatively simple to investigate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30743/discussion-between-rajesh-and-remus-rusanu)